# Javascript Page Load on Last Selected Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap nav-tabs for "Login" and "Register".

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1success" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2success" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And using javascript to remember the last tab the user was on via local storage. The reason I am doing this is because when the user is registering and enters invalid data (submitted form), it reloads the page and returns to the "Login" tab.

I can have the webpage remember the last tab via all the time:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e){
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if (activeTab){
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

But I only want to trigger the code when the form is submitted (not all the time). This is the code I am currently working with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn100").onclick(function ()
    {
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e)
        {
            localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
        });
        var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
        if (activeTab)
        {
            $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
        }
        alert("check if code executed");
    });
</script>
```

I have also tried: `$("#fm100").submit(function ()`, `$("form").submit(function ()`, and creating an HTML `onclick="rememberTab()"` function from the submit button.

I look forward to all your help, thanks!

Comment: Events such as `show.bs.tab` happen before your form is submitted - so if you want to keep using those, you need to react to them when they occur (before the form is submitted), and store the last opened tab somewhere, so that you can access this value again when the form is submitted. A little easier would perhaps be, that you just check which of the LI  in the tab navigation currently has the `active` class. Combine that with .index or sth like that ...

Comment: I am fairly new to this type of code. How do I use indexes? Perhaps a link - or - how to I use my current code to react before the form is submitted?